# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, type-conversion

```
print("Please enter your Weight")
weight = input(">")
print("Please enter your height")
height = input(">")
bmi = weight/height
if int(bmi) <= 18:
print("you are currently under weight")
elif int(bmi)>=24:
print("you are normal weight")
else:
print("you are over weight")
```

Traceback

```
File "C:\Users\reazonsraj\Desktop\123.py", line 6, in <module>
bmi = weight/height
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: You are inputting a string then trying to divide it with a string, convert your input into an int

Comment: use `int`: `int(weight)/int(height)`

Comment: That's not how you calculate BMI, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

When inputting data it is saved as a string. What you need to do is convert it into an int.

```
print("Please enter your Weight")
weight = int(input(">"))
print("Please enter your height")
height = int(input(">"))
bmi = weight/height
if int(bmi) <= 18:
print("you are currently under weight")
elif int(bmi)>=24:
print("you are normal weight")
else:
print("you are over weight")
```

This will solve one problem, but it does not resolve all of them. If you were to enter in a decimal number then you will receive a `ValueError` as `int()` deals with whole numbers. To resolve this issue you will need to use `float()` instead of int.

```
print("Please enter your Weight")
weight = float(input(">"))
print("Please enter your height")
height = float(input(">"))
bmi = weight/height
```

Comment: but when i input height as 5.5 it shows  this error
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.5'

Answer (score 1):

```
def enter_params(name):
    print("Please enter your {}".format(name))
    try:
        return int(input(">"))
    except ValueError:
        raise TypeError("Enter valid {}".format(name)) 
height = enter_params('height')
weight = enter_params('weight')
bmi = int(weight/height)
if bmi <= 18:
    print("you are currently under weight")
elif bmi >= 24:
    print("you are normal weight")
else:
    print("you are over weight")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Please enter your Weight")
weight = float(input())
print("Please enter your height")
height = float(input())
bmi = weight/height
if (bmi) <= 18:
print("you are currently under weight")
elif (bmi)>=24:
print("you are normal weight")
else:
print("you are over weight")
```

Comment: thanks a bunch guys just solved it and got the correct method to do the bmi as well :)